# COUNTIF to calculate number of occurances between 2 values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have no idea what is wrong with my formula and I would like to learn from my mistakes:

I have a range of values, say A1:A100, and I want to count the number of times a value from 0 to 10 appears, 10 - 20 appears etc. and put it into a frequency table.

I am put value 0 and 10 in cells B1 and C1 respectively, 10 and 20 in B2 and C2 respectively etc. (i.e. the frequency table is from columns B to D)

In D1, my formula is:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100,AND(">="&B1,"<="&C1)
```

However, this formula doesn't seem to work and always returns 0. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can enlighten me on why my formula doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your frequency table goes from 0-10 then 10-20, the 10's are going to be counted twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS for multiple conditions.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$100, ">="&B1, $A$1:$A$100, "<="&C1)
```